# Prevent same rows to insert into table

Tags: sql-server, insert

I am trying to skip the rows which contains same data in primary key column
 and insert the result into master table.

I am using distinct keyword also.The rows are distinct but the primary key column contained some same data.

I have tried `IGNORE_DUP_KEY = ON` but one row is getting inserted of the duplicates. I don't want any row that contains duplicate data in primary key column to be inserted

```
SELECT DISTINCT m.Mainname,ipaddress, domain, firstname, lastname,v.id, 
v.idtype,m.SerialNumber FROM firsttable m  INNER JOIN view_sometable v ON 
   v.SerialNumber = m.Mainname
   WHERE m.Mainname Not IN (
                 SELECT Mainname FROM Mastertable) 
          and v.SerialNumber <>''
                 AND v.Mainname<> m.Mainname
                 and m.Mainname IN (select Hostname from firsttable where
          Mainname like 'som-%' OR Mainname like 'li-%' OR Mainname like 'spl-%')
```

From the above select statement,I am able to retrieve the exact data but for on condition I am getting sometimes two distinct rows but the mainname column contains same data which I am unable to skip and resume the insert.

Comment: First, select all distinct values in the primary key field and then feed this into the query as an inner query or join.

Comment: In the above query result i am getting some multiple data in Mainname column and I want to skip all the multiple columns from the result and continue the insertion.Could you give me the query if possible

Comment: Does the row have the same value in only primary key? or all columns? If the duplicate rows do not have the same values in all columns, then you will need to specify the criteria to specify which row to choose.

Comment: only for the serialnumber column the data is different for duplicate primary key columns

Answer (score 0):

You can use `cte` and `Rownumber` to remove duplicate. try this

```
;with cte as(
 SELECT 
 m.Mainname,ipaddress, domain, firstname, lastname,v.id, v.idtype,m.SerialNumber,  
 ROW_NUMBER OVER(partition by YOURPRIMARYKEY order by ASYOURREQUIREMENT) as [Row_Num]
 FROM firsttable m  
 INNER JOIN view_sometable v ON v.SerialNumber = m.Mainname
 WHERE m.Mainname Not IN ( SELECT Mainname FROM Mastertable) 
 and        v.SerialNumber <>''
 AND v.Mainname<> m.Mainname
 and m.Mainname IN (select Hostname from firsttable where Mainname like 'som-%' OR 
     Mainname like 'li-%' OR Mainname like 'spl-%') 
  )

  Select * from cte where [Row_Num]=1
```

Comment: `[Row_Num]` is new added column to cte. Remove where condition from `Select * from cte where [Row_Num]=1` and check `Row_Num` is present in cte or not.